# How to use DbQueryDependency with mongodb in Yii2

Tags: php, mongodb, caching, yii2

I want to use DbQueryDependency caching the `yii\mongodb\Query`, but i get this:

```
[error][yii\base\InvalidConfigException] yii\base\InvalidConfigException: "yii\caching\DbQueryDependency::$query" should be an instance of "yii\db\QueryInterface". in /vendor/yiisoft/yii2/caching/DbQueryDependency.php:78
```

- Mongodb 4.0.8
- PHP 7.2.6
- Yii 2.0.18
- yiisoft/yii2-mongodb              2.1.7
- yiisoft/yii2-redis                2.0.9

```php
class Test extends yii\mongodb\ActiveRecord {
    // ...
    public static function findByTest($test){
        $dep = new DbQueryDependency([
            'query'=> (new Query())
                ->from('test')
                ->where(['test' => $test])
                ->orderBy(['updated_at' => -1 ])
                ->one(),
        ]);

        $cache = Yii::$app->cache;
        $key = 'test.'.$test;

        return $cache->getOrSet($key, function () use ($test) {
            return static::findOne(['test' => $test, 'status' => static::STATUS_ACTIVE]);

        }, 3600, $dep);
    }
    // ...
}
```

I expect the yii caching mongodb document in 1 hour, unless the `updated_at` changed, but the acctual i get the `yii\base\InvalidConfigExc
eption: "yii\caching\DbQueryDependency::$query" should be an instance of "yii\db\QueryInterface".`

How can i fix this? thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove `one()` call from your code. `one()` executes query and return its result, while you need query itself.

Also you may try optimize your query by selecting only max value (or at least setting limit - `one()` does not set limit, so your query returns all data from table ad PHP uses only first record).

```
'query' => (new Query())
    ->select('MAX(updated_at)')
    ->from('test')
    ->where(['test' => $test]),
```

or

```
'query' => (new Query())
    ->from('test')
    ->where(['test' => $test])
    ->orderBy(['updated_at' => SORT_DESC])
    ->limit(1),
```

Comment: Thank you! Another question:
`$dep = new DbQueryDependency([
    'query'=> (new Query())
        ->select(['updated_at'])
        ->from('test')
        ->where(['test' => $test])
]);`

But the DbQueryDependency caching not work! 
The `static::findOne(...);` will execute at every time?
How to let DbQueryDependency work? @rob006